# storing an account number with or without dashes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this has been asked somewhere, but I keep only finding discussions about phone numbers.

I'm designing a system for a supplier group that controls multiple online stores. There are 5 different types/levels of stores (based on their buying group, blah).
These accounts can order products from our warehouse and also have their own collection of customers that can order products from them.

Since both store accounts and their customer accounts will be stored in and accessed by our system, but stores will be accessing their customer accounts independently I want to set up an 'organized' structure for account numbers, that works for both sides of the system.

I was planning on doing 10 digit account numbers, with the first 5 digits identifying the store (the first of which will identify the store type/level), and the last 5 the customer.

For example,

```
First LEVEL1 store account : 10001-00000
Their customer accounts : 10001-00001, 10001-00002, etc.

Third LEVEL2 store account : 20003-00000
Their customer accounts : 20003-00001, 20003-00002, etc.
```

This should allow for enough growth to support our potential number of stores and their number of customers.

**My question is, should I separate the numbers with a dash or not?**

It certainly makes it clearer for humans, but it feels like it would be better in the database to be stored as a true int, though I don't know how often I'd be comparing them, etc.

Should I store it as an INT with no dash, and just format it when displaying it to users? (then obviously be sure to  accept account number input with or without a dash)

Comment: The answer to this is entirely subjective. Why is it called the Blend-O-Tron 9000B and not the Blend-O-Tron 9000/B or 9000-B or 9000+B? You can use any separator you want, but think about the sorts of users you have and if the'll be typing these in, seeing them on invoices, etc. Sometimes shorter is better, in which case AFX00001 might be better than 20003-00001. Letters handle more possibilities in a shorter number of characters.

Comment: Design your tables properly.  This kind of structure will only give you problem later on.  Read some introductory database design books.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!
Yes, it is very subjective. I was more curious what some of the drawbacks to the dashes would be from a systematic view. 

In terms of our users, here at head office we will only be communicating with our dealers (so we'd likely be asking for the first 5 digit section, and then we'd be reviewing accounts under their store) and our dealers would only be dealing with their customers, so they won't EVER need to use an account number with a different starting section. 

I thought the dash would help users understand where the store number ends and user number begins.

Answer (score 3):

1NF says that values in each attribute must be atomic. You are violating the 1NF by adding dashes and storing two attributes as one.

---

**What must you (ideally) do?**

Each store has an ID, so the store's table should have an ID column that contains that.

Next, the customers should also have their own IDs in their table.

Finally, the relationship (or junction) table between store and customer should contain store's ID and customer's ID as each row.

Alternatively, the customer can have a foreign key which tells which store the customer should be shopping from, assuming a customer is tied to only one store.

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion! I have been visualizing user tables all wrong! I don't know why I used a relationship table to associate my products and categories tables but then a foreign key for users and stores. All the reasons I did it for the products are just as applicable to users.

Comment: (I like your name by the way)
I do have a question about this implementation though. If I have 2 stores with unique storeIDs in a stores table, and they each have 2 customers that exist in a customers table. 
Do all the customers really need unique customer numbers? I get why they do from the customer tables perspective (obviously they need a unique primary key), but from the dealers perspective both of their customers could (and debatably should) be 00001 and 00002, but belong to different stores.
I think some of our dealers will question why their 10th customer is 00204.

Comment: @Aaron: The dealer will question about the customer's ID if you expose it to them. Customer's ID is a detail that has been added by you (to uniquely identify each customer). So dealers should not be made privy to that knowledge. Behind the scenes, your code can work with IDs without a problem. Just don't bring it to the front all the way down to the human who is handling his/her store. (1/2)

Comment: If you want to customers to be numbered consecutively for each store, then you should add store's ID as a foreign key to the customer's table and make the combination of {StoreID, CustomerID} as your key for the customer table. (2/2)

Comment: There are many with similar handle like mine.. There's a 'usr', 'HaveNoDisplayName' etc. around.